# Oracle consulta dinâmica em colunas

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql, oracle11g

Estou com a seguinte situação, preciso criar um consulta dinâmica entre as colunas para montagem de um Script. Supondo que existe uma alteração nas versões onde é adicionado uma coluna extra na tabela, o Script devera reconhecer essas alterações sem ter manutenção no mesmo.

No Select deverá retornar coluna1, coluna2, coluna3, coluna 4

Tentei utilizar Listagg porém não atende, pois os valores se transformam em String.

`CREATE TABLE TESTE_STACK(
    COLUNA1 VARCHAR2(4000),
    COLUNA2 VARCHAR2(4000),
    COLUNA3 VARCHAR2(4000)
    );`

```
ALTER TABLE TESTE_STACK add COLUNA4 VARCHAR2(4000);

SELECT Listagg(A.COLUMN_NAME, ',' ) Within GROUP(ORDER BY A.COLUMN_ID) Colunas
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS A
WHERE A.OWNER = ''
AND   A.TABLE_NAME = 'TESTE_STACK';

SELECT (SELECT Listagg(A.COLUMN_NAME, ',' ) Within GROUP(ORDER BY A.COLUMN_ID) Colunas
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS A
WHERE A.OWNER = ''
AND   A.TABLE_NAME = 'TESTE_STACK') 
FROM TESTE_STACK A
;
</i></code>
```

Comment: "... A consulta devera retornar  'coluna1, coluna2, coluna3, coluna 4' ..." isso é uma string, o que você precisa que retorne?

Comment: Preciso que retorno em como se fosse colunas, o retorno com o Listagg já vem em String
Listagg =  'coluna1, coluna2, coluna3, coluna 4'

como se fosse colunas, ou alguma forma de concatenar com o alias
 TESTE_STACK.coluna1, TESTE_STACK.coluna2 ....

Comment: `Listagg(table_name||'.'||column_name,',')`

Comment: Isso concatena com alias, porem ainda fica em formato de String.
Preciso que retorno seja utilizado em outro Select , para definição das colunas

Comment: Por que não fazer um JOIN ?

Comment: Descreva seu problema com mais detalhes

Comment: Mas como seria?.
No cenário que estou preciso montar um Script para fazer updates nas colunas de forma de dinâmica, onde não precise dar manutenção ao realizar um add colunm na tabela

Comment: E se fizer o relacionamento, e a tabela onde terão novas colunas colocar algo como `ALIAS.*` dessa forma se tiver coluna nova ira trazer

Comment: Bom de certa forma consegui resolver a situação para o Script
Porem o retorno no Update não pega o valor da coluna
`UPDATE TESTE_STACK  SET A.COLUNA1 = A.COLUNA1;
`
`DECLARE
  Valor VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN (SELECT a.Column_Name FROM All_Tab_Columns a WHERE a.Owner = 'tst' AND a.Table_Name = 'TESTE_STACK')LOOP
    FOR x IN (SELECT 'A.' || i.Column_Name AS Coluna FROM Teste_Stack a)LOOP
      Valor := x.Coluna;
      Dbms_Output.Put_Line('UPDATE TESTE_STACK '||' SET '||x.Coluna||' = '||Valor||';'||Chr(10));
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;`

Comment: Coloque como resposta, e apague esse comentário

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema utilizando o Execute Immediet, desta forma é possível salvar o valor das colunas em uma variavel para realização do update.
Esse script é utilizando quando existe criação de colunas na tabela, de forma dinâmica ele irá reconhecer a nova coluna e seu valor

```
DECLARE
        VALOR VARCHAR2(4000);
        VSQL VARCHAR2(4000);
        VTABLE VARCHAR2(4000);
        BEGIN 
            VTABLE := UPPER('&TABLE_NAME');
            FOR i IN (
                        SELECT TO_CHAR(a.Column_Name) COL 
                        FROM All_Tab_Columns a 
                        WHERE a.Owner = 'tst' 
                        AND a.Table_Name = VTABLE
            )LOOP 
                    VSSQL := 'SELECT '||I.COL||' FROM '||VTABLE||' ';
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE VSSQL INTO VALOR;
                    Dbms_Output.Put_Line('UPDATE '||VTABLE|| '
                                        ||' SET '||I.Col||' = '||Valor||';'
                                        ||Chr(10)); 

            END LOOP; 
        END;
```